# Copying data to excel using c# code.Duplicate row insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, export-to-excel

I have to copy 500k rows of bulk data to excel using c# code.I get this data as output from a stored procedure in 7 parts. Every time I get the data, I am immediately copying it using response. write and I get the excel in the end. However I am facing the issue of duplicate rows getting inserted in the excel. I am working with vs2008. I am not sure if i can use openxml for this. I have tried using temporary datatables and collating them and later copying them to excel. It was giving the same duplicate entries.

My code:

```
 public void GetReport(string CommandText, int StartIndex)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                // setup command
                command.Connection = cn;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = CommandText;

                // params
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@application_id_array", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100));
                command.Parameters[0].Value = _applicationCSV;

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startIndex", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
                command.Parameters[1].Value = StartIndex * _divisor + 1;

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maxRowCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
                command.Parameters[2].Value = _divisor;

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@region", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
                command.Parameters[3].Value = _region;

                command.CommandTimeout = 60;

                // open connection
                cn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                try
                {  
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Response.Output.Write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}\t{10}\t{11}\t{12}\t{13}\t{14}\t{15}\t{16}\n", reader["ID"].ToString(), reader["description"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["User_Name"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["country_code"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["ref_indicator"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["department"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["employee_indicator"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["phone"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["application_name"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["application_user_logon"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["role"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["ParentTask"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["application_name2"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["application_user_logon2"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["role2"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["conflict_task_name"].ToString(),
                                                                        reader["Exclusion"].ToString());

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }



 protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int pages = _reportRowCount / _divisor + 1;

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report.xls");

        #region using loops
        for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Response.Write("Id\tCategory\tUser Name\tCountry Code\tReference Indicator\tDepartment\tEmployee Indicator\tPhone\tApp Name A\tUser ID A\tApp Role A\tSOD Task Group A\tApp Name B\tUser ID B\tApp Role B\tSOD Task Group B\tApplicable Exclusion\n");
            }


            this.GetReport("sp_GetPaged" + GetStoredProcedureSuffix(), i);              
        }

        Response.End();

        #endregion
    }
```

The _reportRowCount value is the count of the total number if rows which is usually around 500k. _divisor value is a constant=65535.

Comment: Without seeing the buggy code along with a better problem description this is not answerable

Comment: I've edited the question to add the code.